# What is the flags field in system account info?

Tags: accountdata

In the Polkadot-JS UI, one can query account data under [Developer > Chain state > system > account](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/#/chainstate).

[image]

According to [Polkadot Wiki](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-accounts#query-account-data-in-polkadot-js), we know

> `data`, the additional data that belongs to this account. Used to store the balance(s) in a lot of chains.

and

> The `flags` describe extra information about the account.

But what exactly is the extra information? why is it ever needed? and why only some accounts have it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a simple mechanism to indicate whether the new ref-counting logic is in place for this account.
See [the code](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blame/master/frame/balances/src/types.rs#L111) below:

```rs
const IS_NEW_LOGIC: u128 = 0x80000000_00000000_00000000_00000000u128;

#[derive(Encode, Decode, Clone, PartialEq, Eq, RuntimeDebug, MaxEncodedLen, TypeInfo)]
pub struct ExtraFlags(u128);
impl Default for ExtraFlags {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self(IS_NEW_LOGIC)
    }
}
impl ExtraFlags {
    pub fn old_logic() -> Self {
        Self(0)
    }
    pub fn set_new_logic(&mut self) {
        self.0 = self.0 | IS_NEW_LOGIC
    }
    pub fn is_new_logic(&self) -> bool {
        (self.0 & IS_NEW_LOGIC) == IS_NEW_LOGIC
    }
}
```

To understand it better you can check this test too [dispatchable_tests.rs](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/balances/src/tests/dispatchable_tests.rs#L192) where it tests upgrading an account and checking this value:

```rs
assert!(!Balances::account(&7).flags.is_new_logic());

assert_ok!(Balances::upgrade_accounts(Some(1).into(), vec![7]));

assert!(Balances::account(&7).flags.is_new_logic());
```